# iOS Bottleneck: Global variable vs. Core Data or Properity Lists

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ios5, core-data

I'm new to iOS & Cocoa. My question isn't about how to make something work, but more about design to improve UX & performance.

I'm adding features to an existing app. Currently, the app has one class "RootViewController"  (RVC) that is responsible for making server requests. RVC calls a server for a json response. This json response is parsed and the parsed response is referenced by an NSArray object called "array". The data that the server gives to "array" must be updated regularly because it represents live inventory that other customers could buy.

I need to use the reference to "array" in other classes at different times during the lifetime of the app. I don't want to call the server every time I want to use or update "array". When testing this app on my own device, it seems like calling the server can be slow -> hurts performance of the app.

I've considered creating a class that could act as a delegate to keep a reference to an NSArray - sort of acting like a global variable. I'd make an asynchronous request to the server and keep up with the response in this delegate class. I'm not sure how to determine whether this approach is efficient or considers best practices (with MVC in mind).

I'm looking to find out the best place to store "array" so that other classes may use it quickly without depending too much on the network or memory usage. "array" must be able to be updated occasionally from the server (as the "model" may change from inventory changes) . Based on my research, iOS's CoreData seems like the best place to start, but I'm not sure how to update CoreData regularly if the app is not active. In other words, I don't want to present the user with stale data if the data in CoreData hasn't been updated recently.

The json responses are about 20KB - 45KB.

Where is the best/alternate place to store light weight objects so that they can be updated regularly? I'm leaning toward the session style variable, but I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: In first place, I doubt this be *the* bottleneck. If you're a beginner, probably your code quality will affect performance more than the use of CoreData vs. plists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look at this according to MVC, you have two parts:

- An array – this is the model
- The code which fetches the inventory from the server – this is the controller

This controller code is really the model-controller, not the view-controller. I wouldn't put it in a view controller class. You could put it in your app delegate if the code is very simple, but I'd recommend putting it entirely in its own class.

In **-applicationDidFinishLaunching**:

```
[[InventoryController sharedInstance] reloadContent];
[[InventoryController sharedInstance] scheduleUpdates];
```

**InventoryController.h**

```
@interface InventoryController

@property (retain) NSArray *inventory;
@property (retain) NSTimer *reloadTimer;

+ (InventoryController *) sharedInstance;
- (void) reloadContent;
- (void) scheduleUpdates;

@end
```

**InventoryController.m**

```
@implmentation InventoryController

- (void) reloadContent {
    ...
}

+ (InventoryController *) sharedInstance {
    static InventoryController * singleton;
    if (!singleton)
        singleton = [[self.class alloc] init];
    return singleton;
}

- (void) scheduleUpdates {
    self.reloadTimer = ...;
}

@end
```

Everywhere else:

```
NSArray *inventory = [[InventoryController sharedInstance] inventory];
```

In `-reloadContent`, you should pull the content from the server. In `-scheduleUpdates`, you should set up a timer which acts on the controller, causing it to periodically reload data. If your view controller needs to adjust its behavior when the data is stale, store an NSDate alongside the array, add a method like `-isStale` which checks the dates, and invoke that first.

Remember to load URLs in the background. You shouldn't stop and reload data while you're handling an event or action, so in essence, your view controller needs to return from the action method while it's waiting for data, and adjust its display when you get the data back.

If a view controller needs to respond once the data is refreshed, have the view controllers register for a notification which you can post when your inventory controller finishes updating its content:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    postNotificationName:InventoryControllerDidReloadContent
                  object:self];
```

If you want to cache inventory data on the device so you can remove it from memory when the app goes into the background, you might do that by writing the array to a property list, but if stale data isn't useful, you may not want to bother.

You could use Core Data in place of the array and the property list, but it doesn't remove the need for a controller which loads the data from the server and loads it into the context. Instead of having an array, you'll probably have have a managed object context and a fetched results controller. If you're not editing that content in your app I doubt Core Data will provide any benefits over an array and property list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend storing this in your application delegate. It works well to store an array and can be accessed from any class in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If this "array" has interesting structure CoreData is a nice choice.   In this case I'm guessing CoreData and a plist are going to be about as fast as each other.   Use whichever seems simplest and if it is too slow try the other.

Try not to need to update the data while the app isn't running.   Store the last update time with your cached data.   If it is "too old" display a "please wait" placeholder and update it.   If it is "old but not too old" display what you have and update it in a non-main thread.   Or try other variants of that UI ("too old" == notice + read-only mode).

If you do find a trick to updating in the background that gets past app review, think long and hard about how much of your user's battery this will eat.   Add a way to disable it.   Or have it disabled by default and add a way to enable it.    Or just don't do it.  :-)